# Integration testing for google cloud spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Is it possible to launch in memory db like h2 or embedded cassandraunit.

I want to setup embedded spanner db without the needs of google credentials json which connects to a remote spanner db. Is it possible to do that ?

Any pointers for setting it up or testing would be appreciated.

Comment: I have developed a Cloud Spanner emulator for local use for development and test purposes for my JDBC driver (https://github.com/olavloite/spanner-jdbc). It is currently in alpha testing and I expect to release a beta version very soon. Send me a short email if you would be interested in becoming a beta tester for this emulator. You can find my email address on my GitHub profile page.

Comment: Were you able to get this working using the official Google Cloud Spanner Emulator?  I'm running into a related issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189326/running-google-cloud-spanner-emulator-in-azure-pipeline-for-integration-testing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no a native way to use Spanner as an embedded db like H2.

Probably you can try with third-party solutions  or Spanner partners:

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/partners/